# Python module "idios" not found via pip install

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install the package "idios" by doing the following:

```
pip install idios
```

This is recommended by the docs: http://idios.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gettingstarted.html

However, I get the following error message:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement idios (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for idios
```

I am installing it through pip 7.1.2 and Ubuntu 14.04.

This good man feels like crying because he can't find an information on how to work around this and he has just inherited a messy code. :`(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/eldarion/idios#egg=idios
```

or add this to your requirements.txt:

```
-e git://github.com/eldarion/idios.git#egg=idios
```

and run `pip install requirements.txt`

Comment: That was the issue! Thank you so much. Really appreciate it.